# Why does my project copy not compile?

Tags: xetex, overleaf, compilation-error

I want to copy an old project in *overleaf* as I'd like to keep the old version as it is.

When I copy the entire project, the *unchanged* exact copy fails to compile a pdf.

The only difference I found is in the `Raw logs` the original version lists:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.12.13)  9 MAY 2022 09:00
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**cv.tex
(/compile/cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

While the copy has another version:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=xelatex 2021.9.30)  9 MAY 2022 08:59
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**cv.tex
(./cv.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12> (/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
```

How can I make an exact copy, including the correct version?

Answer (score 2):

Click the *menu* button (top right)

[image]

Then find *Settings* and make sure the Compiler it is set to *XeLaTex*

[image]

Then set the > *TeX Live version* to the desired one to match the original one:

[image]